# can you help me to optimize a golang code about function CrossPointTwoRects

Tags: go

below is the defition of a function:

```
func CrossPointTwoRects(rec1, rec2 []int) [][]int {
    crossPoints := make([][]int, 0)
    existed := make(map[string]bool, 0)
    x1 := rec1[0]
    y1 := rec1[1]
    x2 := rec1[2]
    y2 := rec1[3]
    x3 := rec2[0]
    y3 := rec2[1]
    x4 := rec2[2]
    y4 := rec2[3]
    var xs = []int{x1, x2, x3, x4}
    var ys = []int{y1, y2, y3, y4}
    for _, x := range xs {
        for _, y := range ys {
            key := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", x, y)
            if x1 <= x && x <= x2 && x3 <= x && x <= x4 && y1 <= y && y <= y2 && y3 <= y && y <= y4 && !existed[key] {
                crossPoints = append(crossPoints, []int{x, y})
                existed[key] = true
            }
        }
    }
    return crossPoints
}
```

and rect1 and rect2 is four-length array.This  function should execute very quickly, but when you call it many times, it will cost more time, even one call cost 0.5ms, this is so amazing.

Can anyone tell me why? Thank you for your help

Comment: That's not really an optimization. An increasing execution time per execution is a bug in my book. So you may reconsider the title. Mere request for optimization may trigger some users to close-vote.

Comment: Can you include the source data as well to show what performs slowly? Saying it costs 0.5ms without the input data doesn't give us much to help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, readability is paramount.

The title of a classic computer science text is Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs.

---

The data structures are:

```
type Point struct {
    X, Y int
}

type Rectangle struct {
    P1 Point // Min
    P2 Point // Max
}
```

The algorithm is:

```
func CrossPointTwoRects(r1, r2 Rectangle) []Point {
    var crossPoints []Point
    existed := make(map[Point]bool, 0)
    var xs = []int{r1.P1.X, r1.P2.X, r2.P1.X, r2.P2.X}
    var ys = []int{r1.P1.Y, r1.P2.Y, r2.P1.Y, r2.P2.Y}
    for _, x := range xs {
        if r1.P1.X <= x && x <= r1.P2.X && r2.P1.X <= x && x <= r2.P2.X {
            for _, y := range ys {
                if r1.P1.Y <= y && y <= r1.P2.Y && r2.P1.Y <= y && y <= r2.P2.Y {
                    p := Point{X: x, Y: y}
                    if !existed[p] {
                        if crossPoints == nil {
                            crossPoints = make([]Point, 0, 4)
                        }
                        crossPoints = append(crossPoints, p)
                        existed[p] = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return crossPoints
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/7gGc5Xsm1xA

---

Some Go benchmarks:

```
func BenchmarkY(b *testing.B) {
    // Y - Intersection
    r1 := Rectangle{Point{1, 1}, Point{4, 4}}
    r2 := Rectangle{Point{2, 2}, Point{3, 3}}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        CrossPointTwoRects(r1, r2)
    }
}

func BenchmarkN(b *testing.B) {
    // N - No intersection
    r1 := Rectangle{Point{1, 1}, Point{4, 4}}
    r2 := Rectangle{Point{8, 8}, Point{9, 9}}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        CrossPointTwoRects(r1, r2)
    }
}
```

---

Comparable benchmark results:

```
rocka2q:
BenchmarkY-12     8445902    142.8 ns/op    64 B/op   1 allocs/op
BenchmarkN-12   120209712     10.12 ns/op    0 B/op   0 allocs/op

zhuohuashiyi:
BenchmarkYZ-12     872277   1376 ns/op     283 B/op  23 allocs/op
BenchmarkNZ-12    1000000   1147 ns/op      51 B/op  16 allocs/op

coxley:
BenchmarkYC-12    5387480    212.2 ns/op    64 B/op   1 allocs/op
BenchmarkNC-12   13633231     82.94 ns/op   64 B/op   1 allocs/op
```

---

Comment: it is right, but i wonder why your solution is superior to coxley, it is struct works?

Comment: @zhuohuashiyi: There are also significant differences in the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Without exact input data, I'm not able to reproduce a 0.5ms runtime. That being said, this implementation has a lot of allocations for something small.

(Skip to the end if you just want the modified code)

### Problem

```golang
func BenchmarkFoo(b *testing.B) {
    r1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    r2 := []int{1, 2, 50, 100}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        CrossPointTwoRects(r1, r2)
    }
}
```

```
➜ go test -bench=. -benchmem ./...
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: scratch
BenchmarkFoo-10           803174              1481 ns/op             200 B/op         28 allocs/op
PASS
ok      scratch 2.410s
```

28 allocations to check the intersect of two 4-length slices seems like a lot.

You can run `go build -gcflags='m=2'` to understand what escapes to the heap and why, but I'll break it down:

- `crossPoints` escapes because it's a slice that gets returned
- `crossPoints` has a capacity of `0`, so it'll force an extra allocation when we start appending to it.

  - For slices with a capacity < 1024, each append doubles the capacity. This means that we'll do up to 4 allocations, assuming the max number of intersections we have is 4. (cap 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4)
- `fmt.Sprintf` does an allocation for each argument given due to those arguments being an interface.
- The slices we append to `crossPoints` also escape, given that `crossPoints` escapes.

### Optimizing

There are a few points that let us optimize this:

- Each rectangle will be a length of 4
- We don't need string formatting to detect if we've seen a point or not
- We know the maximum number of intersections is equal to the number of points
- We know the maximum number of values for a point is 2

Let's convert everything we can to fixed-length arrays instead of variable-length slices:

```golang
func CrossPointTwoRects(rec1, rec2 [4]int) [][2]int {
    // Given four points, there are a max of 4 points that can intersect
    // There's no harm in setting the worst-case capacity and leaving length=0
    crossPoints := make([][2]int, 0, 4)

    x1, y1, x2, y2 := rec1[0], rec1[1], rec1[2], rec1[3]
    x3, y3, x4, y4 := rec2[0], rec2[1], rec2[2], rec2[3]
    xs := [4]int{x1, x2, x3, x4}
    ys := [4]int{y1, y2, y3, y4}

    seen := map[[2]int]struct{}{}
    for _, x := range xs {
        for _, y := range ys {
            if _, ok := seen[[2]int{x, y}]; ok {
                continue
            }
            if x1 <= x && x <= x2 && x3 <= x && x <= x4 && y1 <= y && y <= y2 && y3 <= y && y <= y4 {
                crossPoints = append(crossPoints, [2]int{x, y})
                seen[[2]int{x, y}] = empty
            }
        }
    }
    return crossPoints
}
```

```
➜ go test -bench=. -benchmem ./...
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: scratch
BenchmarkFoo-10          4575730               252.3 ns/op            64 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      scratch 2.099s
```

With just that, we're down to 1 allocation per operation, reducing runtime by 5x!